# PostgreSQL - getting Too many client repeatedly

Tags: postgresql

I am running PSQL with PostGis extension. After the start of server, after about 3 weeks, I start getting fatal errors for connections with "too many clients already". When I restart the server, problem is gone, but is back again after aprox. 3 weeks.

If I run `pg_stat_activity`, I got

```
SELECT state, count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY state;

"active";2
"idle";944
```

And all idle queries are the same - SELECTs.

I cannot debug this problem and restarting server all over is not a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your application has a connection leak.
There is no way to fix this on the database side - you'll have to change the application so that it closes connections again.

I guess you set `max_connections` so high to work around this problem (1000 is too high).

Comment: Connections with this idle select are from PHP. PHP should close connection at the end of the script.

Comment: @MartinPerry  Perhaps it *should*, but the evidence indicates that it does not.  So this is a PHP problem, not a PostgreSQL problem.

Comment: I have check the code, PHP is closing connections. The idle connections are all from a narrow time window (few minutes), several times a day. But the scripts that runs on the server are used whole day. From logs, there is also no special activity or errors at those "idle" times. Just to be sure, I have explicitely added `$pq = null;` to the end of each script (where `$pq` is my Psql wrapper class)

Comment: @MartinPerry Is there a storm of new script initiations at that point?  What library are you using?  "I have explicitely added $pq = null;"  Does your library provide a specific method such as "$pq->pg_close()" ?  That should be more reliable than hoping the garbage collectors gets around to it.

Comment: There is no difference in server scripts behaviour. I am using plain `pg_connect` and `pg_close` in my own wrapper. `pg_close` is called from class destructor.

Comment: Well, I have added "nulling" of connections, but the problem persist :-( Still getting idle on the same query

Comment: Don't set the variable to `null`, close the connections.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have added close connection before every end of the script (last comand or before die/exit), but the problem persist :-(. Ther are no errors in PHP log

Answer (score -1):

if it possible for you, you can kill the connection based on its idle time but its always better to fix it at app level.